# Looking to Find ALL (with duplicates) values in one column for unique values in another column

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function

I have an Excel table that looks like this:

| Code | Description |
| --- | --- |
| A | Desc1 |
| A | Desc1 |
| B | Desc3 |
| C | Desc4 |
| C | Desc5 |
| C | Desc6 |

I need to find all the Descriptions for each unique Code. For example I want a table that looks like this:

| Code | Description1 | Description2 | Description3 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| A | Desc1 | Desc1 |  |
| B | Desc3 |  |  |
| C | Desc4 | Desc5 | Desc6 |

I am using the following code to find the unique "codes":

```
=INDEX($A$2:$A$2726, MATCH(0, COUNTIF($D$1:$D1, $A$2:$A$2726), 0))
```

But need a formula for populating the descriptions in columns when my list of descriptions include duplicates.

Any suggestion of a formula would be very helpful!

Thank you,

Comment: You question is unclear, please update with screenshot examples of your data. The solution may be as simple as a pivot table, or use of functions for newer excel to VBA for older versions of excel.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming the first table is in columns A and B, and the second in columns C to F (headers from C10 to F10), and assuming you have Excel 365, in C11 enter the formula:

```
=UNIQUE(A2:A7)
```

In D11, enter the formula:

```
=TRANSPOSE(FILTER($B$2:$B$7,$A$2:$A$7=$C11,""))
```

Drag the formula down to fill the other cells.

[image: Results]

Change the ranges to match yours.